# in 3ds format, how do I determine texutre's addressing mode?

Tags: opengl, textures, 3ds

I have a trouble about texture's addressing mode in 3ds file. (not 3ds max)

I succeeded in loading all material information of 3ds file like material color, texture file name and so on. But I couldn't determine texture's addressing mode. For example, a texture of bricks will be repeated, but a texture of doors will not. Of course, I think 3ds file has a information about their addressing mode but I could not find it. (maybe 0xa351?)

Where do I find the information about texture's addressing mode in 3ds file?

Comment: So we got another abandoned question from a one-time-joiner? Otherwise accept and up-vote an answer or ask what you didn't understand. Or maybe you came up with a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right with your guess, as [here](http://www.mediatel.lu/workshop/graphic/3D_fileformat/h_3ds2.html) they say about A351:

```
If read as a short int (ls byte first):

bit4 bit0: 00 tile (default) 11 decal  01 both
bit 1: mirror
bit 2: not used ? (0)
bit 3: negative
bit 5: summed area map filtering (instead of pyramidal)
bit 6: use alpha  (toggles RGBluma/alpha. For masks RGB means RGBluma)
bit 7: there is a one channel tint (either RGBluma or alpha)
bit 8: ignore alpha (take RGBluma even if an alpha exists (?))
bit 9: there is a three channel tint (RGB tint)
... not used (0)
```

I think the `tile` option (bits 0 and 4) could be what you're looking for. I guess when `tile` is on, the texCoords are repeated and otherwise they're clamped.